# Timestamp issue with Amazon CloudWatch Logs integration for Windows event logs

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, event-log, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I've just configured my Windows box to send its *event logs* (System, Security, Application) to Cloudwatch Logs (https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1KG4IKXZ94QFK/Using-CloudWatch-Logs-with-Amazon-EC2-Running-Microsoft-Windows-Server). CloudWatch Logs receives the event logs but they don't have *timestamp*!

It seems we can just set the timestamp for IIS logs, Custom logs, etc., but it's not possible to set the "datetime_format" parameter for Event logs (configuration file: AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json), right?!!
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-cwl.html

If it's right, that's weird!! What can I do with a log record that has no timestamp?!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're viewing your logs from the AWS Management Console you should be able to see the event timestamp by clicking on the "gear icon" from the top right that shows/hides the table columns.

If you're interacting with your log data from the AWS CLI or from the AWS SDK, each log event record should come with [a `timestamp` attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_OutputLogEvent.html).

Comment: Ow, thanks. I hadn't seen that gear icon! Actually I use a Logstash input plugin for reading the logs from cloudwatch logs (https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs).